# What is a female or gender neutral form of gentleman that relays the same tone of respect?

Tags: single-word-requests, politeness, gender-neutral

At my office when referring to customers or external vendors I often use the word *gentleman*. I do this in effort to show that I’m speaking respectfully about them so the content and tone of my statement is less likely to be mistaken. For example, “I spoke with the gentleman about the issue he was having and it turned out he forgot to turn his computer on.”

However, when the subject is a female the use of the word *lady* doesn’t seem to project the same level of intended respect.

Is there an **alternative** female or gender neutral word that I could use in these cases?

Comment: Lady is appropriate.

Comment: Most of the answers are missing the whole point of this question:  *Gentleman* retains connotations of respect that *Lady* has largely lost, so is there a current conversational way of referring to a female customer that does carry those connotations more strongly than lady?  The answer may be "no" but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: @ChrisSunami The answer isn't *no*. The answer is one of societal convention. If you frequently thank your customers who are male with "thank you gentlemen", then you *should* thank your customers who are female with "thank you ladies" - not "thank you gentle persons"; because that *is* respectful, women are **not** neuter and to do otherwise is condescending.

Comment: For work-place specific gender-neutral politically-correct terms refer to the answer by @third-news. Otherwise, as Elliot Frisch has suggested, *lady* is the term you want. But in my opinion, if you're talking about clients of yours, **be gender neutral**. *Lady* can have negative implications in this setting because it is often used in a negative fashion, e.g. *That lady wouldn't stop talking about her cat during her visit to my office*. However, **nobody** would say *That gentleman wouldn't stop--*. There is, unfortunately, a large disparity between the two. Use each in the correct setting.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice It's spelled "Elliott" not "nobody". *That gentleman wouldn't stop calling me **nobody***.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Sorry, I would have tagged you if I were allowed. I was one character short and your name was the last thing I modified in that comment.

Comment: It is unequivocal that *lady* is often said when someone wishes to express their irritation or annoyance with a woman: "Listen lady, I ain't got all day to stand here..." The OP is asking for an expression with the similar positive connotations that *gentleman* has. It is therefore NOT a duplicate question, the two answers provided are *lady* and therefore do not satisfy the OP's request.

Comment: Isn't that a general irritation, "listen buddy (or sir), I ain't got all day to stand here..."

Comment: Thanks for all of the input, all the comments were very educational. @Mari-LouA described my intentions the best. I'm not trying to neuter my female customers, I'm trying to use a word that will consistently relay the tone of respect by those whom I'm talking to. Seeing that lady is the corresponding word to gentleman but it can be misinterpreted thereby voiding the purpose of using it, I’ll stick with customer / colleague / vendor when referring to either gender in a conversation.

Comment: I still hear *ladies* used frequently in some regions, especially the southeastern United States, but in my experience, it’s fallen out of fashion on the West Coast and in the Northeast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, 'lady' has a paternalistic connotation, and it is best to refer to both sexes as clients, customers, vendors, manager, assistant...  -when possible.  IOW, avoid referring to their sex but only their position.

Comment: _Lady_ has a paternalistic connotation (that _gentleman_ doesn’t have)?! Since when? Your advice itself is fine (except for vocative cases—“Thank you, clients!” would probably **not** be appreciated nearly as much as “Thank you, ladies and gentlemen!”, even if the ladies and the gentlemen in case are clients), but the first line seems very odd to me. _Lady_ has lots of connotations, but paternalism isn’t one of them.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 'Ladies and gentelmen' is a specific case where very few people will take offence, but if you refer to an individual woman as a 'lady' (or a group of women as 'ladies'), there's a reasonably good chance that you will annoy her (depending on the prevalence of feminist thought where you live). It's a word with overtones of patronising 1950s newsreels.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I would disagree. Lady has always had paternalistic connotations, for hundreds of years. In fact, it still does, even in other languages, e.g. *madame* from French --> *ma dame* literally meaning *my lady*, implying ownership. 'Back in the day', women were essentially bartering tools and that has just recently started to change. So I agree with Third News in that it is best to avoid using gender-specific terms at all, at least in the workplace, and instead use *positional titles*.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice _Paternalism_ is “the policy or practice on the part of people in authority of restricting the freedom and responsibilities of those subordinate to or otherwise dependent on them in their supposed interest”. I might agree to a certain extent that _lady_ (or at least _madame_) **could** sound a bit like ownership is implied—but restriction of freedom by the authority is not something I can imbue into _lady_ no matter how hard I try. (Note: _monsieur_ means ‘my sire’ as well. ‘My lord’ and ‘my good man’ are similar expressions. They do not connote ownership to me.)

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Would you also argue that, when a peasant says *'of course, my lord!'* he is saying that he *owns* the lord?  No, of course not.  *My lady* does not imply ownership of the lady; it is a way of saying that she is above you in rank.

Comment: Also, no matter how hard I try, I _cannot_ make anything possessive- or sexist-sounding out of phrases like “Excuse me—the lady at reception told me this is where I could find XYZ” or “I believe the person you’re looking for is the lady over there, in the red shirt”. It is _uniquely_ a term used to refer to a woman in respectful terms in such situations.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was trying to communicate that implications for the term that existed hundreds of years ago still exist today. See my comment on the OP's question for *when to use **lady***, because it does have negative implications in some settings which is, again, what I was trying to get across.

Comment: @Anonym No, it doesn't imply ownership, but it *used to*, which was the point. Those negative connotations still exist in some instances of using *lady* today, as well as other negative connotations that have arisen out of usage (see my original comment on the OP's question). If we are to continue this discussion we should definitely do so on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In that context, "lady" becomes a female equivalent to "man", so its respectful connotations are much reduced (but it isn't disrespectful either).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I agree that the safest approach is to use the word customer / colleague / vendor etc. This is due to the fact that despite what the proper use or intent of the word "lady" may be by the speaker, the interpretation by the listener is the part of the communications that I have less control over.

Comment: Another reason to take this approach is that some people now identify as non-binary, and would object that no par of gendered nouns truly includes them.

Comment: The word “lady” never implied ownership of anybody or anything. It literally meant bread-kneader. (The sole evidence given is a mistranslation of a **different** word in a different language, *madame*, which also exactly parallels *monsieur*.) This bizarre form of linguistic prescriptivism does not even get its facts right.

Comment: @Davislor That's an etymological fallacy. Many words meant something different hundreds of years ago. Also, a word can have meanings and implications outside of its dictionary definition. This isn't even close to prescriptivism – though I'm happy you've learnt a new word – since we're just discussing real-world effects of words used in real-world contexts.

Comment: @neonblitzer I was responding to the comment, “I would disagree. Lady has always had paternalistic connotations, for hundreds of years” and “implying ownership,” which are specific etymological claims. We can disagree about the significance of etymology. Independently of that, the etymology in this thread is, in fact, wrong. I made no claim that the meanings of words is fixed to their etymology, and in fact it’s the person I disagreed with who did.

Comment: @neonblitzer Also, telling people that they shouldn’t say some words in common use because they’re sexist is, indeed, linguistic prescritpivism.

Comment: @Davislor The parts you quoted aren't necessarily only supported by etymology. Chris's "madame" example is weak, granted, but the main argument that "lady" has paternalistic connotations can be true regardless.

Comment: @neonblitzer Seriously? You’re insisting that I really did need to be told that the meanings and connotations of words change over time on the basis that “the parts you quoted aren’t *necessarily only* supported by etymology”? I only talked about the etymology. I neither made any of the other claims you are refuting, nor do I believe them.

Comment: @Davislor All right. "The word “lady” never implied ownership of anybody or anything." That's the sentence I took issue with. To a reader it looks like you're opposed to the whole idea, and argue for your position by refuting one example. Can you tell me a more favorable interpretation?

Comment: @Davislor Besides, we're not talking about what's _proper_ language or grammar etc. so it can't be a matter of prescriptivism. We're talking about what's a respectful way to address people.

Comment: @neonblitzer Your first comment was your idea of a respectful way to address people?

Comment: @neonblitzer You’ve already acknowledged that “the sentence I took issue with” was completely correct (“Chris’ ‘madame’ example is weak, granted.”) I was making a simple factual claim about etymology. Ideas are not soldiers. You need to stop jumping to the conclusion that anyone who points out that one argument in favor of a position is flawed must be “opposed to the whole idea.”

Comment: @neonblitzer In any case, since you’ve now clarified that you admit what I actually said was right, and I clarified that I do not hold any of the other positions you wanted to start an argument about, I see no point to continue. We are in agreement about everything, except possibly whether correcting a factual error, if it was made in a political cause, means someone must be on The Other Side.

Comment: @neonblitzer This will probably do no good, but, to clarify one thing that I think might legitimately confuse someone reading what I wrote in haste: my reference to a “bizarre form of prescriptivism” was to what you called an “etymological fallacy.” Namely, the idea that words should be used based on their etymologies rather than how they are understood today. I don’t think we even disagree. Nor is prescriptivism always bad: people really shouldn’t say misogynistic things.

Comment: @Davislor This shoulda been a chat. Anyway – yes, we probably agree. "This bizarre form of linguistic prescriptivism does not even get its facts right" was confrontational so I didn't keep a respectful tone either. (Not saying I had the _right_ to be facetious.) Recap: To many people (in contexts like OP's) the word "lady", due to historical and contemporary baggage _related to viewing women as something men can own_, comes across less respectful than "gentleman". A straight dismissal of any implications with the word wasn't cool IMO. You don't seem to have meant that. So, can we end here? :)

Comment: @neonblitzer Yes, I agree. This seems like a good place to leave it.

Answer (score 6):

Gentlemen and *ladies* lend me your ears! You seem to be looking for *lady*.

Comment: I agree that in this instance, lady would work but unfortunately outside it being paired with gentleman, it’s intended tone can be misinterpreted.

Comment: I have come here in search of an alternative for, "lady," since, "Good afternoon ladies," seems to me  to have a creepy connotation that, "Good afternoon gentlemen," does not, in the setting of a written business salutation.

Comment: Note that, in the traditional form of polite speech where “lady” is parallel to “gentleman,” the rule is *ladies first*. Thus, you would always say, “Ladies and gentlemen.”

Answer (score 5):

A gender-neutral, respectful word to describe a customer is "customer". Even in communications that are likely to be shared with said customer, in practice I've found that the word is far less likely to offend. This is especially true in those cases where your customer *sounds* like a "gentleman" on the phone, but is in fact a "lady" (or vice versa).

Your example phrase would therefore sound just as professional and respectful if spoken thusly:

"I spoke with the **customer** about the issue he was having and it turned out he forgot to turn his computer on."

Of course, using "he" in the same sentence negates the gender neutrality of the term you use no matter how carefully you choose it, but that's far too broad to properly cover in detail here.

Answer (score 3):

How about Madame? Though it isn't a direct parallel to gentlemen I think it shows respect

Comment: **Madam** often refers to an older woman who manages a brothel, escort service or some other form of prostitution, that is, a procuress. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madam#Other_usage

Comment: Madam or Ma'am is widely used as a respectful form of address. "Gentlemen's" is also a term for a public toilet, but that doesn't stop the OP considering it respectful.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany In American English, *madame* and *madam* are pronounced differently.

Comment: But also, “Madam Speaker,” “Madam President,” etc. seem to be accepted respectful forms of address.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the most obvious word here is *gentlefolks*, which until the nineteenth century appeared only and always in the plural.  Shakespeare used it in the plural, as did Thackeray.  Eventually, however, writers towards latter end of Victorian era began to use *gentlefolk* in the singular.

But it does seem a long word, doesn’t it?  As a shorter version, the courageous might make fair use of the noun ***gentles***, especially in the plural.  It’s mostly just an “abbreviation” (as it were), of *gentlefolks*.

From *A Midsummer Night’s Dream*, Act V Scene I:

> **Gentles**, perchance you wonder at this show.
>   But wonder on, till truth make all things plain.
>   This man is Pyramus, if you would know.
>   This beauteous lady Thisbe is certain.

Or at the finale, in Puck’s final address to the audience:

> If we shadows have offended,
>   Think but this, and all is mended,
>   That you have but slumber’d here
>  
>   While these visions did appear.
>   And this weak and idle theme,
>   No more yielding but a dream,
>   **Gentles**, do not reprehend:
>   If you pardon, we will mend.
>   And, as I’m an honest Puck,
>   If we have unearned luck
>   Now to ’scape the serpent’s tongue,
>  
>   We will make amends ere long;
>   Else the Puck a liar call:
>   So, good night unto you all.
>   Give me your hands, if we be friends,
>   And Robin shall restore amends.

The OED does note that *gentle* is rarely used in the singular, but describes this sense as

> One who is of gentle birth or rank.

Nonetheless, saying ***a*** gentle rather than *gentles* in general is long gone.  Even in olden days, *simples* were opposed to *gentles*, as in this OED citation:

- 1882 *Mrs. Raven’s Tempt.* III. 8 
   The simples are not bound to pick up what the gentles throw away.

It is now perceived as archaic, but could work for vocative uses in the right setting — especially if you wish to impart an air of formality or antiquity.

A few examples of using *gentles* this way, which might be a comic “vulgarism” for *gentlefolks*, given by the OED are:

- C. 1590 Greene *Fr. Bacon* x. 16 
   Now, courteous Gentles, if the Keepers girle Hath pleas’d the liking fancy of you both [etc.].
- 1591 *Troub. Raigne K. John*, To Gentlem. Rdrs. (1611) 70 
   Gentles, we left King John repleate with blisse.
- 1599 B. Jonson *Ev. Man out of Hum.* (1600) Prol., 
   Gentles, all I can say for him is, you are welcome.
- 1638 Cowley *Love’s Riddle* v, 
   It’s no matter for that; farewell gentles.
- 1641 Marmion *Antiq*. ɪɪɪ. F 4 a, 
   Gentles I would entreat you a courtesie.

Comment: I like this answer - I learnt some interesting things - but does it really answer the question?  I don't know how most people would react to being called *gentles*, but there would likely be some kind of confusion in their responses.

Answer (score 2):

*Gentleman* was initially a compound noun, composed of *Gentle* and *man*. *Gentle*, here, is derived from French *gentil*, meaning of nobility by birth. As such, *Gentleman* can be considered a sort of synonym or *Lord*, a title for men with female counterpart *Lady.*

With regards to a gender-neutral version, initially *Noble* could be a title used for either gender. Now, though, because the word does not have the exact same meaning, it may not be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

"Lady" *is* the accepted term; perhaps use a capital L.

Comment: Capital L?  Really?  If you write "I spoke with the Lady about the issue", to me it seems to suggest that she is a member of the nobility.  (Or that the writer is a native German speaker.)

Comment: Different strokes. I don't see anything amiss with it.

Comment: I believe It is quite Well Established in the english language Which words in a Sentence are To be capitalized and which Are not...

Comment: Indeed it is, and the evidence supports my conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**gentlelady**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gentlelady), [**gentlewoman**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gentlewoman), and the gender-neutral [**gentle-person**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gentle-person).

> gentlelady: *US* a form of address for a woman
>
> gentlewoman: *(archaic, now rare)* a civilized, educated, sensitive, or well-mannered woman; lady
>
> gentle-person: a person of good family and position; gentleman or lady

Comment: I can't say that I have ever heard *gentle-person* used in my entire life. As well, *gentle-woman* is incredibly uncommon, at least in colloquial English. I would personally *not* suggest using either...

Comment: Sadly, *gentlewoman* and [*goodwife*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goodwife) are *archaic*. *Mistress* is also unusable for different reasons.

Comment: Even if these are actual entries in a dictionary, those entries are missing nuance, or rather the glaringly obvious context that no one in their right mind would use these today, except in much older period pieces.